# How to get the highest and lowest points of the previous candle of the admission price

Tags: pine-script

I have a problem. I want to put stop loss and profit on the highest or lowest point of the candle chart before the entry price. Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
low_bar_before_entry = ta.valuewhen( "insert the name of the entry bar" , low[1], 0)
```

if the entry bar has a name just insert it , or if it has a condition like for example `ta.corssover(high, ta.ema(20))`

just insert the name or the condition and you will get the value of the low of the previous bar , and it will remain fixed until the condition is met again in the future.
same goes with previous high

```
High_bar_before_entry = ta.valuewhen( "insert the name of the entry bar" , high[1], 0)
```